# interior french drain installed causing wall to be wet due to condensation?

Tags: condensation, french-drain

I had an interior french drain installed and I have water condensing on the durawall panel that is installed against the wall above the trench.  The durawall panel runs about 2 feet above floor level.  The wall is wet from the floor up to about a foot.  This is causing my garage to be wet.  Is this normal?

Comment: Please revise to tell us more about the wall construction. Photos would be helpful.

Comment: Is the wall hollow core cinderblocks?  If so, the cores are normally tapped so water empties into the drain system and the wall should not be wet.  If not, it indicates a lot of exterior water getting to the foundation.  How old is the drain system (if very old, it could be silted up, so no longer working).  Also, the basement should not be so humid that water condenses on the walls (you will get mold blooms).  Set up a dehumidifier, and inspect the exterior (grading, downspouts).  Pictures of the interior (walls, drain system area), would be needed for any specific advice.